# How to display a 256x256 grid?

Tags: c++, linux, gnuplot

I have a 256x256 array which I print. It's always a single number ranging from -10 to 50. So e.g., the output file looks like:

5 -10 5 4
1 50 -2 4
5 21 35 11
-10 49 -1 0

but on a 256x256 scale. How can I get a graph of these values? (It's supposed to be a heightmap).

I looked through the GNUPlot documentation but didn't find anything that could help me :/ I have a graph.gp file which looks like this:

```
set autoscale
set xrange [0:256]
set yrange [0:256]
set pm3d
cd 'src'
splot "output.dat"
```

Then I open 'gnusplot' in terminal and write `load "graph.gp"`, but it doesn't even want to load the .dat file, let alone give me a graph. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to use matplotlib (python) to make my figures. To do this using matplotlib, you can use `matshow`. Here's a quick script that you can run:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from matplotlib.pylab import *

data = loadtxt("mydata.dat");

matshow(data)

colorbar()

# leaves figure on screen
# comment out when saving file
show()

# uncomment to save file
#savefig('myplot.pdf')
```

that produces a plot that looks like (note I've just used random data):

[image: matshow]

The function `loadtxt` will take in your data file automatically in the format you have it (integers, seperated by spaces, each row in its own line).

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `matrix` keyword:

```
set pm3d map
splot 'output.dat' matrix
```

You shouldn't have to worry much about setting the limits; they should go from 0 to 256 automatically.  Then if you want to play with the color map, go [here](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/pm3dcolors.html) for examples.